# find out whether a panel is visible or not

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have used a asp.net wizard control where i have used many panels in a wizard step .Each panel has a single class which has style display: none.When the user click on "+" button i toggle the class and changes the visibility to Display:Block and this works fine.Now in order to read the values of the controls from panel i tried to read only the controls whose panel is set to visible.But this does not seems to work it shows visible true for all panels even though it has style display:none

i tried this :

```
 if ((this.Form.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("wizard").FindControl("panel" + i)).Visible)
{
//where i is the current count.I have named panel in a continuous order like panel1,panel2....etc This code executes even if the panel is hidden in browser
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style `display` and control `visibility` are two different things.

If you set control to `Visible='false'`; server won't sent/render this control at all to the client side.
Style `display: none` on the other hand will; it't just won't be shown because of css style.

So `display: none` != `Visible='false'`.

If you need to postback whether `display` is set to `none`; you could add `HiddenField` next to your `panel`; set its value with javascript to `Visible`/`Hidden` and then check `HiddenFiled`'s  value to determine visibility on server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the attributes of an ASP.NET control, by for example accessing

```
Panel1.Attributes[("Style")]
```

Then you can check if the attribute "Style" contains "disyplay:none" styling. You can also view this link here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkeesb2c(v=vs.100).aspx.